# How to fixed the td width in table

Tags: html, css

I use easyui-panel with one table in my project.

I want to fixed each td width:50px;

Here is my code:

```
<div  class="easyui-panel" id="pp"  style="margin-top:30px;width:100%">
        <table class="uTbId"  cellspacing="0" style="width:100%" >
         <tr>
           <td style="position:absolute;width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">stack</td>
           <td style="position:absolute;width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">john</td>
           <td style="position:absolute;width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">stock</td>
           <td style="position:absolute;width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">shansa</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td style="postion:absolute;width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">Joy</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

But it works fail. stack,john and stock are disappear. My table is in an abnormal stat.

When I deleted "position:absolute;width:50px;", all names can be show.like:

```
<div  class="easyui-panel" id="pp"  style="margin-top:30px;width:100%">
    <table class="uTbId"  cellspacing="0" style="width:100%" >
     <tr>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">stack</td>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">john</td>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">stock</td>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">shansa</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">Joy</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

All names can appear without fixed width, but it is not what i want.

Who can help me ?

Comment: why have positioning with absolute?

Comment: I want to fix width of td. Only width:50px; in style, it works fail.And position:absolute is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use unified format, It works OK

The code is:

```
<style>
.uTbId tr td{width:100px;background-color:#fafafa}
.uTbId tr td:hover{background-color:#0000CD;color:green;}
</style>
<div  class="easyui-panel" id="pp"  style="margin-top:30px;width:100%">
    <table class="uTbId"  cellspacing="0" style="width:100%" >
     <tr>
       <td >stack</td>
       <td >john</td>
       <td >stock</td>
       <td >shansa</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Joy</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove both `position:absolute` and `width:50px`.

Removing `position:absolute` and the `width:100%` from the `<table>` should result in what you want. So now your HTML looks like

```
<div  class="easyui-panel" id="pp"  style="margin-top:30px;width:100%">
    <table class="uTbId"  cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
       <td style="width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">stack</td>
       <td style="width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">john</td>
       <td style="width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">stock</td>
       <td style="width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">shansa</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td style="width:50px;background-color:#fafafa">Joy</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

If it doesn't result in what you want, it is possible that some CSS styles are adding additional padding or margins to the `<td>` element. Fire up the developer console (F12 on most browsers) -> right click on your element -> Inspect and in the CSS styles part look at the box model to find out if there is any additional padding/margins being applied

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried css define and it works OK . see my own solution. Actually, css define and <td style=""> define should be same. But css define works OK , the other works fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your HTML talbe to be fixed width, then specify column widths:

```
<div  class="easyui-panel" id="pp"  style="margin-top:30px;width:100%">
    <table class="uTbId"  cellspacing="0" style=" table-layout:fixed;" >
    <col width="5px" />
    <col width="5px" />
    <col width="5px" />
    <col width="5px" />
    <col width="5px" />
     <tr>
       <td  style="background-color:#fafafa">stack</td>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">john</td>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">stock</td>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">shansa</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td style="background-color:#fafafa">Joy</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/56Lc4o44/

Comment: Thank you very much. I use css, and it works OK. However, I don't know the reason that < td style=""> and css define should be same effect.